# LibVLC.NET example crashes on LibVLCLibrary.Load()

Tags: c#, .net, dll, vlc

I downloaded LibVLC.NET and I have libvlc.dll v2.2.0.0. When I run the Tutorial.exe at my side LibVLCLibrary.Load() causes the app to crash. 
Looking into it, I found the crash is occurs in ***libVlcLibrary.cs*** in line
string version = m_libvlc_get_version();

causes the crash. Did anyone face this issue?

Note: I found this link but the crash is before the line checking the version:
[Running LibVLC.NET Example on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885887/running-libvlc-net-example-on-windows-7)

Here is the output from the debugger:

The thread 0x2128 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[5388] Tutorial.vshost.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[5388] Tutorial.vshost.exe' has exited with code 1073741855 (0x4000001f).

Comment: I have the same error, haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: I have moved to using nVLC SDK which has errors but at least it is working better than libVLC